Hi Need to add monaco editor with cucumber support in nextjs project
I Am not able to add monaco editor with cucumber support in nextjs project
I Need to add Monaco editor in nextjs project with cucumber support . Means when any one open Monaco editor in next js He can able to write cucumber test cases along with syntax error message .
